# My program takes too long to respond

Tags: python

I have two videos. One is the original video which is 20 fps and one interpolated to 20 fps from 10 fps. To compare these videos, I got every frame of the videos, then in every frame I recorded the RGB values of every single pixel and compared them. My code runs fine when I compare up to 400 frames. However, when I want to compare more frames, it takes at least 45 minutes which is not convenient. You can see my code below

```
from PIL import Image
from math import sqrt
video1 = []
video2 = []
r_difference = []
g_difference = []
b_difference = []
total_difference = []
difference_per_frame = []
total = 0
newtotal = 0
avg = 0

for a in range(0,2): 
    for b in range(20,827):
        if a == 0:
            im = Image.open('frame%d.jpg' % b)
            pix = im.load()
            for x in range(0,640):#dimension of my videos are 640x480
                for y in range(0,480):
                    video1.append(pix[x,y])#gets the RGB values for every pixel
        if a == 1:
            im = Image.open('frames%d.jpg' % b)
            pix = im.load()
            for x in range(0,640):
                for y in range(0,480):
                    video2.append(pix[x,y])

for x in range(0,len(video1)):
    for y in range(0,3):
        if y == 0:
            r_difference.append(abs(video1[x][y]-video2[x][y]))#calculates the R difference
        if y == 1:
            g_difference.append(abs(video1[x][y]-video2[x][y]))#calculates the G difference
        if y == 2:
            b_difference.append(abs(video1[x][y]-video2[x][y]))#calculates the B difference

for e in range(0,len(r_difference)):
        difference = sqrt(r_difference[e] + g_difference[e] + b_difference[e])#calculates the difference for one pixel
        total_difference.append(difference)

for i in range(0,len(total_difference)):
    total = total + total_difference[i]
    if i % 307200 == 0 and i != 0:
        newtotal = (total / 307200)
        difference_per_frame.append(newtotal)#there are 307200 pixels in every frame(640x480)
        total = 0
    if i == len(total_difference) - 1:
        newtotal = (total / 307200)
        difference_per_frame.append(newtotal)#the left over pixels

for z in range(0,len(difference_per_frame)):
    avg = avg + difference_per_frame[z]
avg = avg / len(difference_per_frame)
print avg#calculates the average difference
```

Is there a way to make the run time shorter

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but you have a couple [for-case sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence) in your code that you might think about redesigning. It wouldn't improve your execution time by a significant degree, but it would aid maintainability.

Comment: Your title implies that your program is not responding, but it's _doing_ something. You have one final printout at the end. If you're looking for reassurance that it's still doing something, add some more prints throughout indicating progress. If you want to just make this faster I'd encourage you to look into the `multiprocessing` module so that this isn't all run in one thread.

Comment: after 45 minutes it printed something but I want to know if it is possible to lower the time needed

Answer (score 0):

Like @Kevin said, you're doing excessive looping with your for-case antipattern. Here are the first 2 loops with that removed which should cut down the runtime a bit:

```
for b in range(20,827):
    frame_pix = Image.open('frame%d.jpg' % b).load()
    frames_pix = Image.open('frames%d.jpg' % b).load()
    for x in range(0,640):#dimension of my videos are 640x480
        for y in range(0, 480):
            video1.append(frame_pix[x, y])  # gets the RGB values for every pixel
            video2.append(frames_pix[x, y])  # gets the RGB values for every pixel

for x in range(0, len(video1)):
    r_difference.append(abs(video1[x][0] - video2[x][0]))  # calculates the R difference
    g_difference.append(abs(video1[x][1] - video2[x][1]))  # calculates the G difference
    b_difference.append(abs(video1[x][2] - video2[x][2]))  # calculates the B difference
```

If you want to drastically improve performance, you'll need to process the frames in parallel. I would encourage you to split the frames into chunks, move your diffing code into functions, and look at `multiprocessing` for processing those chunks of frames independently in each process/thread. Here are the docs to get started: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: I'll look the docs but the reason I have two loops is one of them gets the frames from frame.png other from frames.png I also use python 2.7 so is the name different for python 2.7 or is it the same

Comment: Sorry, I missed the 's' on your frames filename. Updated the code to reflect that. Also, linked you the python 2.7 docs instead.